# LaunchRock CNAME configs, what do they do?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, subdomain

Trying out LaunchRock, and ran across this:

[general-instructions-for-creating-your-cname-record](http://support.launchrock.com/knowledgebase/articles/36690-general-instructions-for-creating-your-cname-recor)

Basically as far as I'm able to tell they only support using your sub-domain as the URL, not having the "launch page" at "subdomain-by-you.launchrock.com".

Guessing the guide to changing the subdomain and CNAME means you create a subdomain and then while the user sees "signup.yoursite.com" the DNS call is really going to LaunchRocks servers and being routed to the custom page you set up with them, though that's just a guess on my part.

Comment: Well, **that you ask** really? How to write rewrite-rules? How DNS-resolver works? And remember - **never, NEVER** use term "subdomain", while you don't know difference between *host in domain* and *subdomain*!!!

Comment: @Lazy Badger: It is unclear if you're telling me something, requesting more information from me, or something else. What is it that you're telling me?

Comment: I see, believ you meant "What are you really asking?" - I'm asking if the direction are followed on the page I linked to what is going on from the user's point of view and on the backend. If you load the page, on the right they list how to setup a subdomain and CNAME on 10+ common hosting providers. If you've still got questions let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Host Name/Alias: Enter the part of the address that you picked in the
>   LaunchRock control panel. For example, if you picked
>   signup.yoursite.com as your address, enter signup.
>
> Value/Destination: Enter sites.launchrock.com.

From user's POV it means:

- While this CNAME for you host (site) is active, any visitor of signup.yoursite.com will see "some page" from launchrock.com server (with personalization for site?)

From backend:

- DNS resolve signup.yoursite.com to IP of sites.launchrock.com.
- Browser send request for `HOST: signup.yoursite.com` to host `sites.launchrock.com`
- Processing rules handle incoming request and map it to *some* local resource (page, logical path launchrock.com/signup.yoursite.com/ ???), which http-server returns back to browser

Comment: At least it's my interpretation of texts

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks - appears to confirm my guess, but in more detail; my guess being: "Guessing the guide to changing the subdomain and CNAME means you create a subdomain and then while the user sees "signup.yoursite.com" the DNS call is really going to LaunchRocks servers and being routed to the custom page you set up with them, though that's just a guess on my part."