# Setting up a LaunchRock page without hosting

Tags: web-hosting, dns, subdomain

Looking to buy a 'dot-com' domain as cheap as possible, and set the DNS to forward to the [LaunchRock](http://launchrock.com/features) service without having to setup a hosting act. Is this possible, and if so how?

I've asked roughly the same question before, though at that point I thought I would have to have a domain and hosting, but in rethinking about it just now, since LaunchRock would be hosting the site via a sub-domain reroute using DNS setting, I'm thinking that I don't even need a hosting account to just run a LaunchRock landing page; though not sure if that's the case, or how it might be done.

Here's the original question, "[LaunchRock CNAME configs, what do they do?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24549/launchrock-cname-configs-what-do-they-do)" ([and answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/24553/2288))-- which includes LaunchRock's "[general-instructions-for-creating-your-cname-record](http://support.launchrock.com/knowledgebase/articles/36690-general-instructions-for-creating-your-cname-recor)",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for a cheap and excellent registrar: namecheap

As you described, in your original question linked, the accepted answer is correct.
You will be able to achieve all this without hosting with most registrars as the setup is only on the "DNS" side and not related to hosting.  More, if let say Launchrock were not supporting CNAMEs, you could still do "URL Frame" which is masquing the destination URL from the browser address bar and the last, URL Redirection.   All thoses methods are working easily under Namecheap's control panel.

Comment: +1 @jflaflamme: "URL Frame" would require a host, not just a domain, right? Also, have to say you including your afflink in the recommendation of namecheap, makes me think your recommendation is only driven by you liking their aff-program.

Comment: Yes i have added my afflink my bad, but it is still a good choice (thanks paulmorriss for removing it, shame on me), however, you don't need a host for URL Frame. And like i said "with most registrars".  Sorry again to provide the afflink, i don't work for them, just a satisfied customer who wanted to help !